# CSS selectors get evaluated right-to-left. Do querySelectorAll() selectors get evaluated that way too?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, selectors-api

Do `querySelectorAll()` selectors get evaluated right-to-left like CSS ones, or does it do so left-to-right?

Comment: I am sure if you follow the maze of the specs you would find out. http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselector :)

Comment: @epascarello. Just read that, it says nothing about the subject. It doesn't surprise me, as the spec shouldn't speak about implementation.

Comment: Note that neither the Selectors API spec nor the Selectors spec says that selectors be evaluated from right to left... it's not wise to just assume that they will always be read that way anywhere you encounter them.

Comment: @gdoron: I'm wondering which tag we should use for such questions, [selectors-api] or [queryselectorall]... more people recognize `querySelectorAll()` as the function name, whereas the spec is called Selectors API. Maybe open a question on meta?

Comment: @BoltClock. Why css selectors isn't enough? what the `selectors-api` adds?

Comment: @gdoron: I noticed that you added the [queryselectorall] tag earlier on, so I just switched that to [selectors-api] which has more questions, since the function itself is part of the Selectors API in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right to left, this why the right side should be more specific than the left side.

> jQuery selectors should get more specific from left to right. Selectors are parsed in reverse order, so making sure that your most specific selector is on the right will increase performance..

It says "jQuery" but it's true for all CSS selectors.

Comment: can you provide the link that quote comes from?

Comment: @eric, [here you go](http://www.tutorialchip.com/jquery/how-to-speed-up-jquery-performance/)

Comment: mmmm, I think that just applies to Sizzle selector engine. Not sure if it's the same in the browser implementations. Although it's a logical way to implement it...

Comment: @iwiznia. As you said, it's the logical way to implement it, so that's probably the way it's implemented... :)